# Firestore Admin SDK - Memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone please explain why the following increases the memory which then doesn't get garbage collected?

[image]

I am running the collection.add() function in a loop rated limited to 450/s as I'm iterating through a CSV file. The memory does not increase if I remove the collection.add() method so I assume it's Firebase consuming the memory.

How can I make sure that memory is released after it has been saved in the database?

My code below, any help appreciated.

```
db.collection("games")
        .doc(req.body.docid)
        .collection("players")
        .doc()
        .add({
          Number: row[0],
          FirstName: row[1],
          Lastname: row[2],
          Email: row[3],
          Prize: row[4],
          gameID: req.body.docid,
          guid: row[5]
        })
        .then(() => {
          progressCount++;
          updateProgress(req.body.docid);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You aren't taking into account the fact that the query might lazily load a bunch of things on the first query, which cannot be unloaded later.  This is pretty typical.  Program memory does not simply drop to zero after it completes some work, waiting for more work to perform.  If you think there is a memory leak, you're going to have to show that memory does not get reclaimed after running code repeatedly, not just once.  And, if that's the case, you should file a bug report with reproduction instructions rather than post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is what I've noticed, after each upload the memory usage increases and stays there until the Dyno runs out of memory. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1nzdloP.jpg). The reason I'm posting here first is because I'm very new to Firestore and wasn't sure if it was me causing the issues.

Comment: Without seeing the **entire** code of your program that recreates a situation that looks like leak, it's not really possible to say.  You might be doing something else wrong.  Filing a bug report is never really a bad thing to do, but you should be ready to provide the complete program and extensive details about its execution so that anyone can reproduce.